# How can I save in vim a file with the actual fold text? ("+-- 43 lines [...]")?

Tags: vim

I am looking for a way to save to a new text file a file that is folded, with all the folds closed. In other words, just as I see it on the screen.

Is it possible?

(I will have to print the code later, and parts of it are irrelevant to my purposes; the folding mechanism would be ideal for this, my other alternative is manually adding "[X lines omitted]" to the saved text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a custom `:RenderClosedFolds` command, which will modify the current buffer / range. It also attempts to maintain the `Folded` highlighting of the original folds.

```
":[range]RenderClosedFolds
"           Replace all lines currently hidden inside closed folds
"           with a single line representing 'foldtext'.
function! s:RenderClosedFolds()
    if line('.') == foldclosed('.')
        let l:result = foldtextresult('.')
        call setline('.', l:result)
        execute printf('syntax match renderedFold "\V\^%s\$" containedin=ALL keepend', escape(l:result, '"\'))
    else
        delete _
    endif
endfunction
command! -bar -range=% RenderClosedFolds
\   highlight def link renderedFold Folded |
\   let g:ingocommands_IsEntireBuffer = (<line1> == 1 && <line2> == line('$')) |
\   if g:ingocommands_IsEntireBuffer | syntax clear renderedFold | endif |
\   let g:save_foldmethod = &l:foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual |
\   execute '<line1>,<line2>folddoclosed call <SID>RenderClosedFolds()' |
\   if g:ingocommands_IsEntireBuffer | setlocal nofoldenable | endif |
\   let &l:foldmethod = g:save_foldmethod | unlet g:save_foldmethod g:ingocommands_IsEntireBuffer
```

Answer (score 3):

Fold your text as needed and then use `:TOhtml` to convert to an HTML file.  This will preserve your folding.  If you need it as a plain text file, you can post-process e.g. with [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/), which renders HTML to text and allows to dump it to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

I have once created a script, that [saves all folds to a new buffer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/dyiOYTTxToo/zjXuhwkHH1cJ).